Why does Hana exclusively care for the English patient in "The English Patient?
In "The English Patient," Hana, a nurse paid by British taxpayers, dedicates herself solely to caring for the English patient, Count Almásy. The issue is that the English patient is not even English; he is a Hungarian national, and Hungary was an enemy state to Britain during World War II.
Several issues come to mind from her exclusive care of a Hungarian.
Legal Concerns: Why is she looking after a Hungarian? Given that Hungary is on the enemy side, Hana will face legal trouble in a military court for providing care to an enemy and neglecting British soldiers.
Inefficient Use of Resources: Why is she focusing on just one patient who is likely to die? This seems like an inefficient use of taxpayer funds, especially when there are many younger British patients who could be saved and cared for. British patients paid taxes for her salary, not the Hungarian.
This aspect of the movie, which won Best Picture, seems perplexing.

There are a bunch of questions here.

I have narrowed down to 1 question. Why is she taking care of a foreign patient exclusively? The rest are discussion of issues related to this question.
